# Angular js : How to load server response in ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, codeigniter, angular-ui-router

I am developing and website in codeigniter and angualrJs.

I an trying to load view in **ui-view** from controller- action of codeigniter using `$state` route method. But I am not getting any response. Is need to use http get method for this.

Below is my code.
app.js

```
 (function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("autoQuote",["common.services","ui.router"]);

    app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider"], function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state("step1", {
              url : "/",
              templateURL : "http://dev.angauto.domain.com/rc1/renderstep/step1"
            })

            .state("step2", {
              url : "/",
              templateURL : "http://dev.angauto.domain.com/rc1/renderstep/step2"
            })
    }
    );
}());
```

common.services.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services",
                ["ngResource"])
}());
```

autoQuoteCtrl.js

```
(function(){
     "use strict";
     angular
     .model("autoQuote")
     .controller("prepareDTO","prepareDTO");

     function prepareDTO()
     {
         var vm = this;
         vm.postAutoQuoteObj = [];
     }

 });
```

html

```
    <script src="<?php echo $assetName; ?>/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $assetName; ?>/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $assetName; ?>/js/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $assetName; ?>/js/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $assetName; ?>/js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $assetName; ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- Application Script -->
    <script src="<?php echo $assetName; ?>/app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- services -->
    <script src="common/services/common.services.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="<?php echo $assetName; ?>/app/ctrl/autoQuoteCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="autoQuote">
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Please suggest me if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

i did notice there is $urlRouterProvider in injecting to function has extra "e"

```
app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider"], function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state("step1", {
          url : "/",
          templateURL : "http://dev.angauto.insurance.com/rc1/renderstep/step1"
        })

        .state("step2", {
          url : "/",
          templateURL : "http://dev.angauto.insurance.com/rc1/renderstep/step2"
        })
}
);
```

}());

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KOMMDwLIgWxgBsgXOOvV?p=preview)

You are almost there.. just UI-Router places vies into targets named **`ui-view`**, not the *`ng-view`*

```
//<div ng-view></div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

And also, to use array for IoC, we need array which will encapsulate even the function *(check the removed `]` sign before function)*

```
//app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider"], function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state("step1", {
          url : "/",
          //templateURL : "http://dev.angauto.domain.com/rc1/renderstep/step1"
          templateUrl: "tpl.html"
        })

        .state("step2", {
          url : "/step2",
          //templateURL : "http://dev.angauto.domain.com/rc1/renderstep/step2"
          templateUrl: "tpl.html"
        })
}]
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KOMMDwLIgWxgBsgXOOvV?p=preview)

There is [another example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0xZfU1LzdSNQBPwu4DpM?p=preview)

which uses **`templateUrl`** (instead of template) but not *`templateURL`*

```
    $stateProvider
        .state("step1", {
          url : "/",
          //templateURL : "http://dev.angauto.domain.com/rc1/renderstep/step1"
          templateUrl : "rc1/renderstep/step1.php"

        })

        .state("step2", {
          url : "/step2",
          //templateURL : "http://dev.angauto.domain.com/rc1/renderstep/step2"
          templateUrl : "rc1/renderstep/step2.html"
        })
```

Comment: updated with ui-view, but no change, no ui change shown on page.

Comment: I found your second bug, fix it, created a plunker and extended my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Here I want to use codeIgniter to get view on UI, From codeigniter action I can send view in json object. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, is it related to your question? Or brand new one.. I know lot about UI-Router.. no idea about codeigniter... so?

Comment: Yes, it is related to my question. As I wan to show server response in UI, in ui-view

Comment: Look, I took your code snippets, and as they are, I placed them into plunker.. and it is working. If you do also inject some parts into that on a server (PHP scripts) ... they just must generate the same results.. as I used (and it seems that you are almost there, right).. so.. I made your example working, by fixing the syntax and using ui-view. The Server part is now in your hands, but as a concept - it should/must work

Comment: thank you. can I use templateURL : "http://dev.angauto.domain.com/rc1/renderstep/step1" like that to get response. or need o use http service for this.

Comment: Have you tried? you can of course use any http call, but usually it should be relative url (to avoid any CORS issues) there is adjusted plunker with the templateUrl http://plnkr.co/edit/0xZfU1LzdSNQBPwu4DpM?p=preview. **BUT**  use `templateUrl` not *templateURL*... Url not URL